# Using LIKE with list of values from subquery

Tags: sql-server

I have a table of comment posts where occasionally the OP "shouts-out" another poster (so the text looks like `'%@Id%'` where the Id is the Id of another poster in that thread).
I'm trying to come up with some kind of query so I can return the original post and shout-out comments. I thought I could maybe do this with a recursive query, but I'm getting an error code.

```
SELECT p.CreatedBy AS OP, p.Post AS FirstPost, c.Comment AS ShoutOut
    FROM Posts p INNER JOIN Comments c ON p.Id=c.PostId
    WHERE p.CreatedBy=c.CreatedBy AND c.Comment LIKE '%' + 
        (SELECT cc.CreatedBy
            FROM Comments cc
            WHERE cc.PostId=p.Id) + '%'
```

This is returning

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 190 "Subquery returned more than 1
>   value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows <, >, >=, <=,
>   =, != or when the subquery is used as an expression."

Any ideas about what I should be doing instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LIKE` is operator on two scalar values, so it expects the right side to be a single value. But the query returns many - so you get an error.

Instead of single `LIKE` you need `EXISTS` condition (I don't have SqlServer nearby to check syntax though), which check if there is any other comment in `cc` that satisfy the LIKE condition:

```
...  
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Comments cc 
            WHERE cc.PostId = p.Id AND 
                c.Comment LIKE '%' + cc.CreatedBy + '%')
```

Another way to express this is 3-way JOIN:

```
SELECT p.CreatedBy AS OP, p.Post AS FirstPost, c.Comment AS ShoutOut
FROM Posts p 
INNER JOIN Comments c ON p.Id = c.PostId
INNER JOIN Comments cc ON p.Id = cc.PostId
WHERE p.CreatedBy = c.CreatedBy AND 
      c.Comment LIKE '%' + cc.CreatedBy + '%'
GROUP BY OP, FirstPost, ShootOut
```

This version needs a GROUP BY to eliminate duplicate though - as a single ShootOut might be joined with multiple comments from `cc` by the same author. So this might be less efficient (but one needs to look at the query plan to tell for sure).

Comment: Awesome, the three-way join worked great. Thank you!! Is there a reason I should use GROUP BY instead of SELECT DISTINCT?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT should work here too, absolutely. Probably same execution plan, but  SELECT DISTINCT is more idiomatic, you are right.

Comment: Also, please mark it as answer if it worked - this does the community when next people find this quest.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will get you close:

```
SELECT p.CreatedBy AS OP, 
p.Post AS FirstPost, 
c.Comment AS ShoutOut
FROM Posts p 
INNER JOIN Comments c 
  ON p.Id=c.PostId
INNER JOIN Comments so
  ON CHARINDEX(c.Comment,'%@' + cast(so.Id as varchar(8)) + '%') > 0
WHERE p.CreatedBy=c.CreatedBy
```